# What is wrong with my code in java iterators

Tags: java, file, iterator

I am writing a file explorer

```
ArrayList<File> folders = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(parent
                .listFiles(filter)));

ListIterator<File> it = folders.listIterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {

            File file = it.next();

            if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                ArrayList<File> subFolders = new ArrayList<File>(
                        Arrays.asList(file
                                .listFiles(filter)));
                for (File sub : subFolders) {
                    it.add(sub);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mediaFiles.add(file);
            }

            it.remove();

        }
```

When the code reaches to the `it.remove();` I get the following error:

```
02-04 23:32:47.670: E/AndroidRuntime(20230):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-04 23:32:47.670: E/AndroidRuntime(20230):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 23:32:47.670: E/AndroidRuntime(20230): Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
02-04 23:32:47.670: E/AndroidRuntime(20230):    at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:71)
```

Comment: The javadoc for remove states that you can not call the list iterator remove after you've called list iterator add method.  You need to call list iterator next or previous methods.   Take a look at the ListIterator remove method javadoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @chancea.

I had to change my code to the following lines to implement BFS search:

```
    Queue<File> queue = new LinkedList<File>();
    queue.add(parent);

    ArrayList<File> mediaFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        File file = queue.remove();

        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            ArrayList<File> subFolders = new ArrayList<File>(
                    Arrays.asList(file
                            .listFiles(filter)));
            for (File sub : subFolders) {
                queue.add(sub);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mediaFiles.add(file);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Quoting the [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove()) of remove:

> Removes from the list the last element that was returned by next() or previous() (optional operation). This call can only be made once per call to next or previous. **It can be made only if add(E) has not been called after the last call to next or previous**.

Additional information quoted from the docs regarding the remove method:

> Note that the remove() and set(Object) methods are not defined in terms of the cursor position; they are defined to operate on the last element returned by a call to next() or previous().

So therefore if you call `add(E)` within the iteration you cannot call `remove()` also.

I would put the `remove()` method in the `else` statement:

```
else
{
    mediaFiles.add(file);
    it.remove();
}
```

that way It will not be called if you call `add(E)`

However the remove method is **optional** as you are allowed to continually call the `next()` method without making calls to `remove()`.  So you could just omit it completely which may be your desired result.

Comment: What? I should remove the first item in each iteration. It is a BFS search

Comment: @Breceivemail remember the `Remove` method is optional, calling `next()` repeatedly would be completely acceptable